# Предлагаю объединить метки [object] и [объекты]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) и [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b). Главной сделать [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b).

Обе метки не имеют описания. У одной метки *123* вопроса, у другой *105*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метки объединены. Для ускорения процесса бывает полезно [писать в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39761917#39761917) :)